# Scroll bar appearing at the bottom of webpage

Tags: html, scrollbar, document-body

I have a page and cannot understand why there is a bottom nav scroll bar appears.
[The coffee market](http://thecoffeelocator.com/market/)
It appears that some element is off screen but I cannot understand what!
Solution welcome!
Thanks

Comment: hell of a CSS, used firebug with no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the top menu.

Inside the element #categories_block_left there is an UL that is not positioned properly because it pushes the container out of the layout.

what about positioning with a float?

you could use:

`#categories_block_left ul.trees 
    {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;}`

Comment: I usually develop with firefox using: firebug and web-developer.
With web developer I like the function that outlines the elements. By outlining the elements, I could see the problem.

Comment: Cooll thanks. Me too - firebug, which also has outline tool, but it was not picking up the prob here.

Answer (score 1):

find this in global.css on line 269, i think

```
   width: 1050px;
```

omit this line or set

```
   width: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<div id='page'>` your CSS for margin is set to `margin: 0 auto;`

Set it to `margin: 0 0;` (or remove the margin attribute entirely) and the scroll bar goes away.

**Edit:** Tested in Chrome with the dev tools, not sure about other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the 'width' css property from the '#categories_block_left' div removes the horizontal scrollbar and does not seem to affect the page's layout.